# Google maps does not initialize first time

Tags: google-maps, model-view-controller, jquery-mobile, initialization

i gave link page with google maps 
when i clicked map link it opens page but does not initialize google maps.But when i refresh page it initialize page
   [you can click map link in the footer](http://teknonova.com/Map)

it will open [that page](http://teknonova.com/Map/Home/Index1) but without initialize google maps but if you refresh page it will initialize
what should i do to find problem?

Comment: @Kev: What's unclear with this question?

Comment: @Dr.Molle - the question relies entirely on external links. It was a toss up between closing as too localized and NARQ.

Comment: i gave external links as demo.So if any one interest this guestion it will open demo and  with and use browser developer tool

Comment: and also this question is not about server side it is about client side so best option is giving link .i can give all codes but you can view source...so what is best option ?givin all code or link?  @dr.Whole?  if you want i can give all code in the next reply maybe you will help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with jquery-mobile, but I guess that when a page is loaded via AJAX(and the page will be loaded via AJAX in this case, when you click the button), only the content of the div with `data-role="page"` will be loaded into the page.

Your scripts(especially the one that initializes the map) currently are not located inside this div, therefore they will not be loaded or executed.

Comment: you closed my questions i ama angry with you:) but for answer thank you very very much ... according your answer i see my mistake

Comment: I didn't close your question, I was wondering why this question has been closed

Comment: sorry Dr.Molle and thank you.Your solution works .thanks again